# Short story about surfing a monster wave on an alien planet; probably 1960s or '70s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Maybe 30 years ago I read an exciting short story about a man who surfs a giant, perhaps tidal wave on an alien planet. It's a life-threatening adventure with dozens of participants lasting a day or two which requires large funds for participation. Basically a once-in-a-lifetime thing, like climbing the Everest, but those who make it or even win become instant legends.

Our hero catches the wave, barely fights off dangerous sea creatures, manages to stay on his board in spite of his exhaustion and finally becomes disoriented and half-unconscious, thinking he lost the wave and is out of the race. He is rescued and only then learns that he has made it the farthest of them all and is now a celebrity.

Even after explicitly excluding "silver" from my google queries I could not find a reference. But the story was fun to read and I cannot imagine that it has been forgotten among enthusiasts. Who can help me? (I want to read it to my 11 year old son :-).)

Comment: Boy howdy, but I want to see a mashup of that with the Miller's world from interstellar! :D

Comment: @Lexible Don't leave me Murph!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Surfeit, Alan Dean Foster, 1982.  Collected in the anology "...Who Needs Enemies", Del Rey, 1984.

Comment: Could you please add some more details as to how this matches the description in the question?

Comment: @Mithrandir It does contain all the details I remembered in my post. Thanks, Dosco.